# ReactiveCocoa - Stop the triggering of subscribeNext until another signal has been completed

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm pretty new to FRP and I'm facing a problem:

I subscribe to an observable that triggers `subscribeNext` every second.

In the `subscribeNext`'s block, I `zip` observables that execute asynchronous operations and in `zip`'s `completed` block I perform an action with the result.

```
let signal: RACSignal
let asynchOperations: [RACSignal]
var val: AnyObject?

// subscribeNext is trigered every second
signal.subscribeNext {
  let asynchOperations = // several RACSignal

  // Perform asynchronous operations
  RACSignal.zip(asynchOperations).subscribeNext({
    val = $0
  }, completed: {
    // perform actions with `val`
  })
}
```

I would like to stop the triggering of `subscribeNext` for `signal` (that is normally triggered every second) until `completed` (from the `zip`) has been reached.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd choose RAC2, RAC3 works better with swift anyway

Comment: RAC3 is for iOS8+ and I need to be iOS7 compliant.

Comment: Subscribing to a signal within a signal is almost always a code smell. Try flat mapping your outer signal to your inner signal. This wont fix your problem but is a general RAC tip.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an `RACCommand`.

A command is an object that can perform asynchronous operations, but only have one instance of its operation running at a time. As soon as you tell a command to start `execute:`ing, it will become "disabled," and will automatically become enabled again when the operation completes.

(You can also make a command that's enabled based on other criteria than just "am I executing right now," but it doesn't sound like you need that here.)

Once you have that, you *could* derive a signal that "gates" the interval signal (for example, `if:then:else:` on the command's `enabled` signal toggling between `RACSignal.empty` and your actual signal -- I do this enough that I have a helper for it), or you can just check the `canExecute` property before invoking `execute:` in your subscription block.

---

Note: you're doing a slightly weird thing with your inner subscription there -- capturing the value and then dealing with the value on the completed block.

If you're doing that because it's more explicit, and you know that the signal will only send one value but you feel the need to encode that directly, then that's fine. I don't think it's standard, though -- if you have a signal that will only send one value, that's something that unfortunately can't be represented at the type level, but is nonetheless an assumption that you can make in your code (or at least, I find myself comfortable with that assumption. To each their own).

But if you're doing it for timing reasons, or because you actually only want the *last* value sent from the signal, you can use `takeLast:1` instead to get a signal that will always send exactly one value right at the moment that the inner signal completes, and then only subscribe in the `next` block.

---

Slight word of warning: `RACCommand`s are meant to be used from the main thread to back UI updates; if you want to use a command on a background thread you'll need to be explicit about the scheduler to deliver your signals on (check the docs for more details).

---

Another completely different approach to getting similar behavior is temporal recursion: perform your operation, then when it's complete, schedule the operation to occur again one second later, instead of having an ongoing timer.

This is slightly different as you'll *always* wait one second between operations, whereas in the current one you could be waiting anywhere between zero and one seconds, but if that's a not a problem then this is a much simpler solution than using an `RACCommand`.

ReactiveCocoa's `delay:` method makes this sort of ad-hoc scheduling very convenient -- no manual  `NSTimer` wrangling here.

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanation! I didn't know RACCommand. Finally after few researched, I ended up doing this: I wrapped the `zip` operation with the `map:` and `concat` methods and I perform the desired action with the `val` in the `subscribeNext` after `map:` and `concat`